# htaccess mod_rewrite server error

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I try to make nice URLs with following htaccess entries:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w]+)/?([\w]+)?$ /index.php?subdir=$1&page=$2 (works fine)
#RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?([^/]+)?$ /index.php?subdir=$1&page=$2 (doesn't work: 500 Int.Serv.Error)
```

(This one isn't much important to me, since, the first regex works, but if I understand this problem maybe the next problem I understand too)

So with the following line I'll try to get the rest of the query string

```
#RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?([\w]+)?(.*)$ /index.php?subdir=$1&page=$2&$3 (doens't work: 500 Int.Serv.Error)
```

Can someone explain, what I'm doing wrong? I have read something about  that a wrong regex can create an endless loop. Maybe I've got one or two here?

Thanks in advance and regards
doc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query string isn't available as part of the `RewriteRule`, you'd have to capture and examine it in separately in a `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ...`

However, you don't need to actually need to capture the rest of the query string in the rewrite, you can just use the `QSA` or `Query String Append` flag in your rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w]+)/?([\w]+)?$ /index.php?subdir=$1&page=$2 [QSA]
```

Comment: Now I get "Not Found" Message. Without a third param it is ok.

Comment: What is the original URL you're entering?

Comment: I have to ask if it is right to link like this: www.example.com/sub_x/page_x&ID=someID

Comment: so what happens if you directly enter `example.com/index.php?subdir=sub_x&page=page_x&ID=someID`?

Comment: Works fine. But I wan't to use the nice links or am I getting something totally wrong with this rewriting?

Comment: Well that's what the rewrite is writing it to so you must be doing something else, or you have some other rules interfering elsewhere. Though, you did enter the link wrong... It should be: `www.example.com/sub_x/page_x?ID=someID` so try that first

Comment: thats it. Thanks. I just thought the "?" was used alread and that I have to write "&". But.. yea.. "rewrite" ;)